# insert data frames in email body using mailR

Tags: r

I am constrained to a virtual machine which automates scripts.

I am wondering if it is possible to insert data frames (which may be of different dimensions each day) along with static text (preferably html, but plain text can work) into the email.

I tried using R2HTML but it isn't supported on the machine. Neither is sendmailR, only mailR.

edit : knitr is not supported either.

Comment: Why aren't those packages "supported"? And can you give an example how you would like those "data frames" to look like in the email? Just like an HTML table?

Comment: I would like for it to look like an html table. - although basically anything resembling the result of print(df) would work.  I'm not sure why they aren't supported, but the machine returns errors when I install.packages("R2HTML") - and other packages